# PHP phone preg_match

Tags: php, match

For a class I need to do a preg_match for a phone number. The number must match this format (###) ###-####. If the format is incorrect I need to send the user to the form to have the number filled out again. If a match is found I need to allow the form to go through.

My instructor had us write it as such:

```
$PhonePattern = "\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d";
if (!preg_match($PhonePattern, $Phone))
{
header('location:CreateAccount.htm');
exit();
}
else 
{
$Phone = $_GET['txtPhone'];
}
```

This does not work. Can it be changed to:

```
if (!preg_match('/\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d/', $Phone))
{
header('location:CreateAccount.htm');
exit();
}
else 
{
$Phone = $_GET['txtPhone'];
}
```

Comment: Please discuss this with your constructor for a better learning experience.

Comment: @hakre, the first example given was what the instructor recommended I use. Upon error checking I found this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is *one* way:

```
'/^\(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}$/'
```

I added [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Otherwise, you were close.

Learn more about [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info). They are a power tool. But *with great power, comes great responsibility*.

Comment: Testing the new code does not work either. If I comment the code out my form is submitted. With the code in place I am sent back to the form to resubmit all information.

Comment: Define *does not work*? Shouldn't the user be sent back to the form if the phone number is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, but even if the phone number is correct I am sent back to the form.

Comment: The problem is not with the regex, but your code. I encourage you to update your post, or make a new one since this deals with the regex.